# mongo I/O Error Timeout when using rust tokio

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm building an application to process a lot of information on each file and save them in mongo.
There are around 1 million files.
And in each file there can be from 100 to 400 grouped information.

So the logic on my rust code is loop every file.
In each file loop, i then `iter` and `collect` each grouped information in a `tokio::spawn` (save into mongo with `update_one` `upsert` `true`) into a `vec` which then use in `future::try_join_all`.

The mongo collections have indexes including the parameter used for `update_one` - `find` match.

Sometimes in the middle of this process, i get:

```
Error { kind: ConnectionPoolCleared { message: "Connection pool for localhost:27017 cleared because another operation failed w
ith: Kind: I/O error: timed out, labels: {}" }, labels: {"RetryableWriteError"}, wire_version: None, source: None }
```

and because of `try_join_all`, the loop gets terminated - which is what i want.
but the problem now is that i cannot pass this 1 particular file because the error above keeps on showing up.

what does that error means and how do I fix it?

Note: modifying the file as a workaround is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried to search what that error message means?